# CLion Debugging (C program): error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10e285d20)

Tags: c, macos, clion, jetbrains-ide, lldb

I am debugging my program written in C language and need to evaluate expression:

```
(int)strlen((char*)final_string)
```

but error occur:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10e285d20).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

I suppose this error is wrong because of accessing an existing variable.

### 1. EDIT:

I also include what I have tried.
[image]

### 2. EDIT:

Testing code:
[image]

[image]

The problem is that `strlen()` works in code but not in debug.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: You should not be doing casts.

Comment: If I don't do casts, then other errors occur, please look at included EDIT part of the question

Comment: According to the debugging messages, `final_string` is an array of 360 characters. But the result of `strlen` is undefined (and can cause errors) if the array does not contain a null character. I am sorry, but without a reproducible [mre] I cannot say more...

Comment: What errors do you get without casts? Please add exact and complete error message together with matching code into your question.

Comment: That message "strlen has unknown return type" might indicate that you forgot to include the mandatory headers. With that incomplete snippet only guessing is possible,

Comment: If you don't use casts and other errors occur it means you are using the wrong types in your declarations.

Comment: The need for casts is just in the expression evaluator, and doesn't show a problem with the code.  In general, debug information for an app does not include signatures for functions USED by your code, just what is defined by it, so the expression evaluator in the debugger has no way of knowing what "strlen" actually is, requiring the casts, but only in the expression evaluator.

Comment: As others have said, when I try just the example test function that you cite, and stop either at the strlen line or the `}` at the end of the function, running the strlen expression works correctly, so there's something your report is not capturing.  If you  want to investigate further, run your expression in the debugger console like: `expr -u 0 -- (int) strlen(aaa)`, then when that crashes the program will be left in the state where it crashed (probably somewhere in strlen) and you can look at the execution to see what is causing the crash.

Comment: Also, make sure you are building your code `-O0`.  Particularly for fairly trivial code like this, the optimizer can make all sorts of transformations that make it hard to look at variables after the fact.